# SQL join for parent and child records in a link table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm struggling to create a SQL statement that returns both the parent and child records in a single query.

These are my tables....

**COURSE**

```
COURSE_ID | COURSE_CODE
----------+------------
912689    | AUS_COURSE
912389    | AUS_FH1
912769    | AUS_FH2
912528    | AUS_SSMOC1
912293    | AUS_UNIT1
912295    | AUS_UNIT2
912303    | AUS_UNIT3
```

**COURSE_LINKS**

```
COURSE_ID_FROM | COURSE_ID_TO
---------------+-------------
912689         | 912293
912689         | 912295
912689         | 912303
```

So as you can see in my link table **AUS_COURSE** has 3 child records, **AUS_UNIT1**, **AUS_UNIT2**, and **AUS_UNIT3**

I would like my query to somehow return both parent and child records from the COOURSE table, so the output would be something like...

```
COURSE_ID | COURSE_CODE
----------+------------
912689    | AUS_COURSE
912293    | AUS_UNIT1
912295    | AUS_UNIT2
912303    | AUS_UNIT3
```

I'm struggling with working out what join to use and what field to join on

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join the tables by using IN(child,parent) and distinct to drop the duplicates, like this:

```
SELECT distinct c.course_ID,c.course_code
FROM COURSE c
INNER JOIN COURSE_LINKS cl
 ON(c.course_ID in(cl.course_id_from,cl.course_id_to))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a subselect instead of a join.

```
select COURSE_ID, COURSE_CODE from COURSE 
where COURSE_ID in (select COURSE_ID_FROM from COURSE_LINKS) 
OR COURSE_ID in (select COURSE_ID_TO from COURSE_LINKS)
```

Comment: It's unnecessary to select from course_links twice.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks like he needs the values in both columns of COURSE_LINKS.

Comment: Well, that's a whole different approach. Your answer has no subselects and is probably faster in most cases. If performance is not a big issue, I'd prefer subselects for readability though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` for this:

```
SELECT COURSE_ID, COURSE_CODE
FROM COURSE
WHERE COURSE_ID = 912689

UNION ALL

SELECT c1.COURSE_ID, c1.COURSE_CODE
FROM COURSE AS c1
JOIN COURSE_LINKS AS c2 ON c1.COURSE_ID = c2.COURSE_ID_TO
WHERE c2.COURSE_ID_FROM = 912689
```